# What do the keywords "Some" and "Simple" do in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get more in the habit of programming by giving myself a directed task, and the one I found to [create a toy layout engine](http://limpet.net/mbrubeck/2014/08/08/toy-layout-engine-1.html) seemed to be a good match. Since I'm focusing on learning Python, I figured it would be good practice to convert the tutorial into Python. I figured at the same time, this would teach me something about Rust, and about reading code in general. A win all around!

I'm having a difficult time understanding what the keywords (are they even keywords?) `Some` and `Simple` do. They show up in the code presented:

```
enum Selector {
    Simple(SimpleSelector),
}

struct SimpleSelector {
    tag_name: Option<String>,
    id: Option<String>,
    class: Vec<String>,
}
```

I gather that an enum is a way of storing data that may be (exactly) one of several possible types, but I don't see what this means here.

Another thing that shows up in the author's code is (for example)

```
match self.next_char() {
    '#' => {
        self.consume_char();
        selector.id = Some(self.parse_identifier());
    }
```

In this case, I have no idea what the term `Some` does. I have tried looking through [the official Rust documentation](https://www.rust-lang.org/) but I cannot find a description of these terms, even though `Some` is used in the documentation!

What do these terms do? More generally is there a list of Rust keywords? No searching for "rust programming language keywords" seems to be helping.

Comment: Hm, you have an odd combination of languages to learn at the same time. Rust and Python are *very* different, not only by syntax but also the data model is quite distinct (as you probably learned from the answers).

Comment: Fair enough, although my question is more about what exactly these words mean, since I can't find any actual documentation that explains them.

Comment: this still has not been answered for quite some time it seems.

Comment: Regarding `Some`, the documentation for the `Option` type isn't too shabby.... https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/

Answer (score 11):

Rust features [Algebraic Data Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) which in short are data types with several possible shapes, for example:

```
 enum OptionInt {
     None,
     Some(i32),
 }
```

Is a data type which is either `None` (a singleton value) or `Some(i32)` (an `i32`). In this case, `None` and `Some` are *data constructors*: when applied to a value (or without any value in the case of `None`) they produce a value of type `OptionInt`.

Those data constructors will also appear in pattern-matching:

```
match an_option_int {
    Some(an_integer) => 3 * an_integer,
    None => 0
}
```

is an expression that will produce an `i32` which is either:

- `0` if `an_option_int` contained `None`
- or `6` if `an_option_int` contained `Some(2)`

This features is also known as *tagged unions*.

Comment: That doesn't really explain to me what Some does. What is the difference between Some(int) and int?

Comment: With respect to the match example, am I correct to read that as "match the variable named an_option_int. If it is of the type of an integer, do... otherwise, return 0." I suppose that I don't really get the difference between 2i and Some(2i).

Comment: `2i` is an integer. `Some(2i)` is either a pattern (on the left side of `=>`) or an expression (on the right side of `=>`), when an expression it *constructs* a value of type `OptionInt` with the value `Some(2i)` whose memory representation will be somewhat like a tuple `(Some, (2i))`: the first element identifies the type -- either `None` or `Some` -- and the second element is the content -- `()` if `None`, and `(2i)` if `Some`. I advise you to read more on Algebraic Data Types, they are an essential part of many functional programming languages. Corey also provided a link to the guide.

Comment: @Simon Rose I don't know Rust, but from the answer, OptionInt looks like Haskell's Maybe. If that's the case, Some represents the result of a computation that might have failed. If it did fail, it will return None (representing a null value), or Some (value) if it succeeded. You should be able to unwrap the OptionInt using pattern matching to get a "normal int". You could model this in Python by allowing a function to either return a value, or the global Null value if it fails, then just do a check after along the lines of "if result not == null" (or however that would be written in Python).

Comment: @SimonRose: another example that might help you : `enum Outcome { Success(String), Error(String) }`. Here, both variants of the `Outcome` enum contains the same type of data (a `String`), only their variant names change (`Success` and `Error`).

Answer (score 4):

These are not keywords, they are giving names to the variants of the enum. [Relevant section in the guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/enums.html). The list of keywords [is in the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/keywords.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's not a keyword. It's just an enum variant, one that gets imported by default. The documentation is [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html)

You can find a bit more about how enums work here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/enums.html

Option is basically a nullable. Rust doesn't have `null`, but if you want to talk about a value that may not exist, you use `Option<WhateverTypeThatValueIs>`. When it does exist, it will be a `Some(value)`, else `None`.

Example:

```rust
let x: Option<u32> = Some(2);
assert_eq!(x.is_some(), true);

let x: Option<u32> = None;
assert_eq!(x.is_some(), false);
```